# archlinux: how to find a file for install with pacman?

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

Question is really simple: I want to get the package which contain a file,in this example I will use "ifconfig".

On Centos I use

```
yum --whatprovides *bin/ifconfig
```

On debian I can use

```
apt-file search *bin/ifconfig
```

And on Archlinux with pacman?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
pacman -Fy
pacman -Fs whatever_file
```

First command pulls the latest databases of files, second one searches for the file you are looking for(in this example `whatever_file`).

[You may want to read here further](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman#Search_for_a_package_that_contains_a_specific_file)