# /usr/bin/which on Arch

Tags: arch-linux, docker, pacman

I'm missing the `which` command in my Arch Linux container.

In my host distribution (`Ubuntu`) it sits at `/usr/bin/which`, I've done a `pacman -Ss which` followed by `pacman -S core/gnutls` but it's still not available. How do I get it installed in my `Arch` container?

`pacman -Qo /usr/bin/which` only gives me
`error: No package owns /usr/bin/which`

Comment: Try `pacman -Fs which`.

Comment: BAM!, That was it, I did a `# pacman -Fy which ` followed by `pacman -Fs which` and then `pacman -S core/which`, cool! Thank you! You can move this to an answer and I'll accept!

Comment: Related to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/426296/archlinux-how-to-find-a-file-for-install-with-pacman

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pacman -Fy $filename` is used to find the package which provides *$filename*.